# Soma de valores de uma coluna em PHP

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando somar os resultados de uma coluna SQL, porém não retorna nada na minha função.

Aqui tenha uma função que retorna todos os dados na tabela `registros` e a função que deveria somar os valores da coluna `valor`.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    include_once('conexao.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registros";
    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM registros";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dados['id']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['valor']?></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    }
    while($dados2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2))
    {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12 float-left mt-3"><?php echo $dados2['total'] ?>   </div>
    <?php 
    }
?>
```

O primeiro `while` retorna corretamente todas as linhas da tabela com `id` e `valor`. O segundo `while` que chama o `$sql2` não retorna nada.

Gostaria de entender o que fiz de errado.

Comment: Cadê o fechamento do `tbody` e da `table`? Pelo código, vc está colocando uma div no meio da table. Em relação à soma, testei aqui e funcionou normalmente. Qual é o tipo de dado na coluna `valor`?

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
include_once('conexao.php');
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registros");

$total = 0;
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $total += $dados['valor'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dados['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados['valor']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
<div class="col-md-12 float-left mt-3"><?php echo $total; ?>   </div>
```

Dessa forma atribuimos $total, para uma soma dentro do seu loop, com isso você irá obter o resultado do total, note que antes do loop definimos ele como zero.